# How to parse JSON Object without array (Map String) in Flutter

Tags: flutter

My structure JSON is below :

```
{"success":[
   {"id_lawatan":94, "id_lokasi":117, "id_tujuan":5, "tkh_lawatan":"2020-12-21 09:57:46"},
   {"id_lawatan":95,"id_lokasi":117,"id_tujuan":6,"tkh_lawatan":"2020-12-21"}
]
}
```

**My structure Model :**

```
class HistoryModel {    
    final int idlawatan;    
    final int slug;   
    final int tujuan;    
    final DateTime tkhLawatan;    

  HistoryModel({this.idlawatan, this.slug, this.tujuan, this.tkhLawatan});

factory HistoryModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) {     
  return HistoryModel(      
     idlawatan: json['id_lawatan'],     
     slug: json['id_lokasi'],     
     tujuan: json['id_tujuan'],     
     tkhLawatan:DateTime.parse(json['tkh_lawatan'])    
  );  
}
}
```

**My Class Service**

```
 class HistoryService {    
  Future<List<HistoryModel>> getHistory() async {     
    List<HistoryModel> historys;    
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();    
    final extractedUserData =   
        json.decode(prefs.getString('userData')) as Map<String, Object>;     
    var token = extractedUserData['token'];        
    
    final url = apiURL + '/historyUser';
   
    try {
      var jsonResponse = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(url),
          headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer $token"});
      print("message");
      if (jsonResponse.statusCode == 200) {
        print("message2");
       
        final jsonItems = json.decode(jsonResponse.body);
          print(jsonResponse.body);
        historys = jsonItems
            .map<HistoryModel>((json) => HistoryModel.fromJson(jsonItems))
            .toList();        
        print("message3");    
      }
      print(historys);
    } catch (e) {}
    return historys;
  }
}
```

My problem is Output for return historys is null. but the output for print(jsonResponse.body) is has data.

Could anyone help me in this matter. Almost two weeks i cannot solve this issue. My due date is within two week next year 2021. Appreciate so much because i'm to new in flutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because you have to parse the values paired with "success".

Instead of this:

```
historys = jsonItems
            .map<HistoryModel>((json) => HistoryModel.fromJson(jsonItems))
            .toList();
```

do it like this:

```
historys = jsonItems
                .map<HistoryModel>((json) => HistoryModel.fromJson(jsonItems["success"]))
                .toList();
```